# angular cdk 8.2.3 stepper module does not exports cdkStep?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm having problems using the cdk stepper module "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",

I'm coding a component that would make use of cdkStepper

the component is defined in a module that imports CdkStepperModule

```
<div cdkStepper>
      <cdkStep></cdkStep>
 </div>
```

cdkStep is not a known element:
If 'cdkStep' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-stepper-using-the-cdk-stepper) Angular material tutorial

Each step needs to be wrapped inside a `<cdk-step></cdk-step>` tag.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/api#CdkStep

Comment: Can you please elaborate your response? giving an example of the custom stepper can help